# How to require a schema for map type input variables in terraform?

Tags: terraform

The title might not be the best. Ultimately, I want to require default tags for AWS resources in Terraform. `tags` is a map type variable. I don't want to set default values. I want to require someone to specify specific tags in the environment variables, .tfvars, or command line.

**Essentially, I want to require a map type variable be provided with a specific schema.**

I have tried the following...

For the resource I will declare:

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "tfstate" {
    bucket = local.tfstate_bucket

    tags = merge(
        local.default_tags,
        {
            "my:custom" = "customvalue"
        }
    )
}
```

In locals I will declare:

```
locals {
    default_tags = merge(
        var.default_tags,
        {
            "my:service" = "storage"
            "my:app" = "shared"
        }
    )
}
```

In variables I will declare:

```
variable "default_tags" {
    type = object({
        "my:environment" = string
        "my:owner" = string
    })
    description = "Default tags for AWS resources."
    nullable = false
}
```

This will require specifying a `default_tags` variable with `my:environment` and `my:owner` values.

However, Terraform does not like the `"` in the identifier, and without the `"` it doesn't like the `:` in the identifier. This leads me to believe I am doing this wrong. I need the flexibility to use the `:` in the tag name for AWS. Instead, I get the error:

```
│ Error: Invalid type specification
│ 
│   on variables.tf line 4, in variable "default_tags":
│    2:     type = object({
│    3:         "my:environment" = string
│    4:         "my:owner" = string
│    5:     })
│ 
│ Object constructor map keys must be attribute names.
```

How can I achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 4):

How about we use a `type = map(string)` but then we put validation in place:

```
variable "default_tags" {
  type = map(string)

  default = {
    "my:enviro" = "a"
    "my:owner"  = "b"
  }

  validation {
    condition = alltrue([
      for k, v in var.default_tags :
      contains(["my:environment", "my:owner"], k)
    ])
    error_message = "Missing required keys"
  }
  validation {
    condition     = length(var.default_tags) > 1
    error_message = "Missing required keys"
  }
}
```

that will fail because in the default we provide `"my:enviro"` instead of the full environment

```txt
Planning failed. Terraform encountered an error while generating this plan.

╷
│ Error: Invalid value for variable
│ 
│   on main.tf line 30:
│   30: variable "default_tags" {
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.default_tags is map of string with 2 elements
│ 
│ Missing required keys
│ 
│ This was checked by the validation rule
```

---

We can have multiple validation clauses:

```
variable "default_tags" {
  type = map(string)

  default = {
    "my:enviro" = "a"
    "my:owner"  = "b"
  }

  validation {
    condition     = can(var.default_tags["my:environment"])
    error_message = "Missing my:environment keys"
  }

  validation {
    condition     = can(var.default_tags["my:owner"])
    error_message = "Missing my:owner keys"
  }
}
```

that way the error could be more specific

Comment: Yes, I considered validation. If this is the best way, I will give it a shot. I kind of wanted to know that I’m approaching this correctly to begin with. Thank you.

Comment: A `validation` block is definitely the best way to do this. However, the validation in this answer would pass with an empty variable value e.g. `{}`, and so there should be a second validation block to ensure the length is > 1.

Comment: @Appleoddity ... Ye validation can do what you need, I added a second example ... I feel validation is better as we can provide very descriptive messages

Comment: Good catch @MatthewSchuchard I corrected that and added a second example that covers the case without adding length

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map(string)` and then a validation rule to enforce your conditions.
For example

```
variable "default_tags" {
  type        = map(string)
  description = "Default tags for AWS resources."
  nullable    = false

  validation {
    condition     = alltrue([for k in keys(var.default_tags) : contains(["my:environment", "my:owner"], k)]) && length(keys(var.default_tags)) == 2
    error_message = "Variable must contains keys \"my:environment\" and \"my:owner\" only."
  }
}
```

Edit: I realised only after posting, that a similar answer had already been provided. Only noteworthy difference with the great answer by [@Helder Sepulveda](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7599833/helder-sepulveda), in this one the validation also enforces that the two keys are the only keys provided in the map.

Comment: +1 ... just one comment, break your long conditions into multiple lines to make the code a bot more readable